# Issue with Jquery load functionality

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I am trying to run the Page with Jquery Functionality insside it, what is happening when i do the ajax POSt, it shows me the message successfully in an alert box and afterwards it reloads the whole page again and then it is unable to run again and at point it shows error like

```
$fancybox in undefined, sometimes it shows t is undefined
```

but other functionality like update the page again does not work. Here is the below code i tried

```
<html>
<head>
<title>View Images</title>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/fancybox/jquery.fancybox-1.3.4.pack.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/fancybox/jquery.easing-1.3.pack.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/fancybox/jquery.mousewheel-3.0.4.pack.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/js/fancybox/jquery.fancybox-1.3.4.css">
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("a.zoom2").fancybox({
        'zoomSpeedIn'     :500,
        'zoomSpeedOut'   :500,
        'overlayShow'     :false,
        'width'         :800,
        'height'           :600
    });

    $(".mychecks").click(function(e) {
        var data = $("#frmImages").serialize();
        var mainID = $("#mainID").val();
        $.ajax({
            type:"POST",
            url:"actionImages.cfm?action=update",
            cache:false,
            data:data,
            success:function(html) {            
                var i = $("#msg").html(html).text().replace('/\s+/g', ' ');
                alert(i);
                $('#reloadImages').load('viewImages.cfm?ID=' + mainID + '&user=myname');                
            }
        });
    });
});
function checkboxes(theElement) {
    var theForm = theElement.form, z = 0;
        for(z=0; z<theForm.length;z++){
        if(theForm[z].type == 'checkbox' && theForm[z].name != 'checkall'){
        theForm[z].checked = theElement.checked;
        }
    }
} 
</script>
</head>
<body style="background:white;">
<div id="reloadImages">
  <form name="frmImages" id="frmImages">
    <table align="center" width="100%" cellpadding="1" cellspacing="2">
      <tr>
        <td colspan="4" align="center"><div style="display:none;" id="msg"></div></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td colspan="4" align="left" class="BlackBold20"><strong>View Images</strong></td>
      </tr>
      <td height="30" valign="middle" class="dropdownb"><a class="zoom2" rel="group" title="Bigger Image" 
            href="/small/5643-Freshy_FRESH_OVAL_OVAL.jpg"> <IMG src="/small/5643.jpg" border='0'></a><br>
          <a title="Delete this Image - 5643.jpg" style="cursor:pointer;" id="Del~47780~5643" class="del">[X]</a>&nbsp;&nbsp; <br>
          Show Image:  
          Yes
          <input type="radio" name="display_47780" id="display_1_47780" checked="checked" value="1" title="Check this Radio to show the image on front screen">
          &nbsp;&nbsp; 
          No
          <input type="radio" name="display_47780" id="display_0_47780"  value="0" title="Check this Radio to not show the image on front screen">
          <br>
          <br>
          <select name="submitter_47780" id="submitter_47780">
            <option value="none" selected="selected">(Select One)...</option>
            <option value="cDM" selected="selected">cDM</option>
          </select>
          <br>
          Header Image&nbsp;&nbsp;
          <select name="headerImage_47780" id="headerImage_47780">
            <option value="0" >No</option>
            <option value="1" selected="selected">Yes</option>
          </select></td>
        <td height="30" valign="middle" class="dropdownb"><a class="zoom2" rel="group" title="Bigger Image" 
            href="/small/5643-Chrysanthemum_13D4294A55.jpg"> <IMG src="/small/5643-Chrysanthemum_13D4294A55.jpg" border='0'></a><br>
          <a title="Delete this Image - 5643-Chrysanthemum_13D4294A55.jpg" style="cursor:pointer;" id="Del~47787~5643" class="del">[X]</a>&nbsp;&nbsp; <br>
          Show Image:  
          Yes
          <input type="radio" name="display_47787" id="display_1_47787" checked="checked" value="1" title="Check this Radio to show the image on front screen">
          &nbsp;&nbsp; 
          No
          <input type="radio" name="display_47787" id="display_0_47787"  value="0" title="Check this Radio to not show the image on front screen">
          <br>
          <br>
          <select name="submitter_47787" id="submitter_47787">
            <option value="none" selected="selected">(Select One)...</option>
            <option value="cDM" selected="selected">cDM</option>
          </select>
          <br>
          Header Image&nbsp;&nbsp;
          <select name="headerImage_47787" id="headerImage_47787">
            <option value="0" selected="selected">No</option>
            <option value="1" >Yes</option>
          </select></td>
        <td height="30" valign="middle" class="dropdownb"><a class="zoom2" rel="group" title="Bigger Image" 
            href="/small/5643-Desert_73A8B513FA.jpg"> <IMG src="/small/5643-Desert_73A8B513FA.jpg" border='0'></a><br>
          <a title="Delete this Image - 5643-Desert_73A8B513FA.jpg" style="cursor:pointer;" id="Del~47788~5643" class="del">[X]</a>&nbsp;&nbsp; <br>
          Show Image:  
          Yes
          <input type="radio" name="display_47788" id="display_1_47788" checked="checked" value="1" title="Check this Radio to show the image on front screen">
          &nbsp;&nbsp; 
          No
          <input type="radio" name="display_47788" id="display_0_47788"  value="0" title="Check this Radio to not show the image on front screen">
          <br>
          <br>
          <select name="submitter_47788" id="submitter_47788">
            <option value="none" selected="selected">(Select One)...</option>
            <option value="cDM" selected="selected">cDM</option>
          </select>
          <br>
          Header Image&nbsp;&nbsp;
          <select name="headerImage_47788" id="headerImage_47788">
            <option value="0" selected="selected">No</option>
            <option value="1" >Yes</option>
          </select></td>
        <td height="30" valign="middle" class="dropdownb"><a class="zoom2" rel="group" title="Bigger Image" 
            href="/small/5643-Hydrangeas_B1AE8A300E.jpg"> <IMG src="/small/5643-Hydrangeas_B1AE8A300E.jpg" border='0'></a><br>
          <a title="Delete this Image - 5643-Hydrangeas_B1AE8A300E.jpg" style="cursor:pointer;" id="Del~47789~5643" class="del">[X]</a>&nbsp;&nbsp; <br>
          Show Image:  
          Yes
          <input type="radio" name="display_47789" id="display_1_47789" checked="checked" value="1" title="Check this Radio to show the image on front screen">
          &nbsp;&nbsp; 
          No
          <input type="radio" name="display_47789" id="display_0_47789"  value="0" title="Check this Radio to not show the image on front screen">
          <br>
          <br>
          <select name="submitter_47789" id="submitter_47789">
            <option value="none" selected="selected">(Select One)...</option>
            <option value="cDM" selected="selected">cDM</option>
          </select>
          <br>
          Header Image&nbsp;&nbsp;
          <select name="headerImage_47789" id="headerImage_47789">
            <option value="0" selected="selected">No</option>
            <option value="1" >Yes</option>
          </select></td>
        <span class="dropdownb">
        </tr>
        </span>
        <td height="30" valign="middle" class="dropdownb"><a class="zoom2" rel="group" title="Bigger Image" 
            href="/small/5643-Jellyfish_BFEB8F8D8F.jpg"> <IMG src="/small/5643-Jellyfish_BFEB8F8D8F.jpg" border='0'></a><br>
          <a title="Delete this Image - 5643-Jellyfish_BFEB8F8D8F.jpg" style="cursor:pointer;" id="Del~47790~5643" class="del">[X]</a>&nbsp;&nbsp; <br>
          Show Image:  
          Yes
          <input type="radio" name="display_47790" id="display_1_47790" checked="checked" value="1" title="Check this Radio to show the image on front screen">
          &nbsp;&nbsp; 
          No
          <input type="radio" name="display_47790" id="display_0_47790"  value="0" title="Check this Radio to not show the image on front screen">
          <br>
          <br>
          <select name="submitter_47790" id="submitter_47790">
            <option value="none" selected="selected">(Select One)...</option>
            <option value="cDM" >cDM</option>
          </select>
          <br>
          Header Image&nbsp;&nbsp;
          <select name="headerImage_47790" id="headerImage_47790">
            <option value="0" selected="selected">No</option>
            <option value="1" >Yes</option>
          </select></td>
        <td height="30" valign="middle" class="dropdownb"><a class="zoom2" rel="group" title="Bigger Image" 
            href="/small/5643-Koala_3BF9D36D8F.jpg"> <IMG src="/small/5643-Koala_3BF9D36D8F.jpg" border='0'></a><br>
          <a title="Delete this Image - 5643-Koala_3BF9D36D8F.jpg" style="cursor:pointer;" id="Del~47791~5643" class="del">[X]</a>&nbsp;&nbsp; <br>
          Show Image:  
          Yes
          <input type="radio" name="display_47791" id="display_1_47791" checked="checked" value="1" title="Check this Radio to show the image on front screen">
          &nbsp;&nbsp; 
          No
          <input type="radio" name="display_47791" id="display_0_47791"  value="0" title="Check this Radio to not show the image on front screen">
          <br>
          <br>
          <select name="submitter_47791" id="submitter_47791">
            <option value="none" selected="selected">(Select One)...</option>
            <option value="cDM" selected="selected">cDM</option>
          </select>
          <br>
          Header Image&nbsp;&nbsp;
          <select name="headerImage_47791" id="headerImage_47791">
            <option value="0" selected="selected">No</option>
            <option value="1" >Yes</option>
          </select></td>
        <td height="30" valign="middle" class="dropdownb"><a class="zoom2" rel="group" title="Bigger Image" 
            href="/small/5643-lamborghini-82a_05F51070AB.jpg"> <IMG src="/small/5643-lamborghini-82a_05F51070AB.jpg" border='0'></a><br>
          <a title="Delete this Image - 5643-lamborghini-82a_05F51070AB.jpg" style="cursor:pointer;" id="Del~47792~5643" class="del">[X]</a>&nbsp;&nbsp; <br>
          Show Image:  
          Yes
          <input type="radio" name="display_47792" id="display_1_47792" checked="checked" value="1" title="Check this Radio to show the image on front screen">
          &nbsp;&nbsp; 
          No
          <input type="radio" name="display_47792" id="display_0_47792"  value="0" title="Check this Radio to not show the image on front screen">
          <br>
          <br>
          <select name="submitter_47792" id="submitter_47792">
            <option value="none" selected="selected">(Select One)...</option>
            <option value="cDM" >cDM</option>
          </select>
          <br>
          Header Image&nbsp;&nbsp;
          <select name="headerImage_47792" id="headerImage_47792">
            <option value="0" selected="selected">No</option>
            <option value="1" >Yes</option>
          </select></td>
        <td height="30" valign="middle" class="dropdownb"><a class="zoom2" rel="group" title="Bigger Image" 
            href="/small/5643-Lighthouse_5D01293FFF.jpg"> <IMG src="/small/5643-Lighthouse_5D01293FFF.jpg" border='0'></a><br>
          <a title="Delete this Image - 5643-Lighthouse_5D01293FFF.jpg" style="cursor:pointer;" id="Del~47793~5643" class="del">[X]</a>&nbsp;&nbsp; <br>
          Show Image:  
          Yes
          <input type="radio" name="display_47793" id="display_1_47793" checked="checked" value="1" title="Check this Radio to show the image on front screen">
          &nbsp;&nbsp; 
          No
          <input type="radio" name="display_47793" id="display_0_47793"  value="0" title="Check this Radio to not show the image on front screen">
          <br>
          <br>
          <select name="submitter_47793" id="submitter_47793">
            <option value="none" selected="selected">(Select One)...</option>
            <option value="cDM" >cDM</option>
          </select>
          <br>
          Header Image&nbsp;&nbsp;
          <select name="headerImage_47793" id="headerImage_47793">
            <option value="0" selected="selected">No</option>
            <option value="1" >Yes</option>
          </select></td>
        <span class="dropdownb">
        </tr>
        </span>
        <td height="30" valign="middle" class="dropdownb"><a class="zoom2" rel="group" title="Bigger Image" 
            href="/small/5643-Penguins1_714BCABE16.jpg"> <IMG src="/small/5643-Penguins1_714BCABE16.jpg" border='0'></a><br>
          <a title="Delete this Image - 5643-Penguins1_714BCABE16.jpg" style="cursor:pointer;" id="Del~47794~5643" class="del">[X]</a>&nbsp;&nbsp; <br>
          Show Image:  
          Yes
          <input type="radio" name="display_47794" id="display_1_47794" checked="checked" value="1" title="Check this Radio to show the image on front screen">
          &nbsp;&nbsp; 
          No
          <input type="radio" name="display_47794" id="display_0_47794"  value="0" title="Check this Radio to not show the image on front screen">
          <br>
          <br>
          <select name="submitter_47794" id="submitter_47794">
            <option value="none" selected="selected">(Select One)...</option>
            <option value="cDM" selected="selected">cDM</option>
          </select>
          <br>
          Header Image&nbsp;&nbsp;
          <select name="headerImage_47794" id="headerImage_47794">
            <option value="0" selected="selected">No</option>
            <option value="1" >Yes</option>
          </select></td>
        <td height="30" valign="middle" class="dropdownb"><a class="zoom2" rel="group" title="Bigger Image" 
            href="/small/5643-sameera-reddy-77a_1C7F77BE41.jpg"> <IMG src="/small/5643-sameera-reddy-77a_1C7F77BE41.jpg" border='0'></a><br>
          <a title="Delete this Image - 5643-sameera-reddy-77a_1C7F77BE41.jpg" style="cursor:pointer;" id="Del~47795~5643" class="del">[X]</a>&nbsp;&nbsp; <br>
          Show Image:  
          Yes
          <input type="radio" name="display_47795" id="display_1_47795" checked="checked" value="1" title="Check this Radio to show the image on front screen">
          &nbsp;&nbsp; 
          No
          <input type="radio" name="display_47795" id="display_0_47795"  value="0" title="Check this Radio to not show the image on front screen">
          <br>
          <br>
          <select name="submitter_47795" id="submitter_47795">
            <option value="none" selected="selected">(Select One)...</option>
            <option value="cDM" selected="selected">cDM</option>
          </select>
          <br>
          Header Image&nbsp;&nbsp;
          <select name="headerImage_47795" id="headerImage_47795">
            <option value="0" selected="selected">No</option>
            <option value="1" >Yes</option>
          </select></td>
        <td height="30" valign="middle" class="dropdownb"><a class="zoom2" rel="group" title="Bigger Image" 
            href="/small/5643-Tulips_F832F5324B.jpg"> <IMG src="/small/5643-Tulips_F832F5324B.jpg" border='0'></a><br>
          <a title="Delete this Image - 5643-Tulips_F832F5324B.jpg" style="cursor:pointer;" id="Del~47796~5643" class="del">[X]</a>&nbsp;&nbsp; <br>
          Show Image:  
          Yes
          <input type="radio" name="display_47796" id="display_1_47796" checked="checked" value="1" title="Check this Radio to show the image on front screen">
          &nbsp;&nbsp; 
          No
          <input type="radio" name="display_47796" id="display_0_47796"  value="0" title="Check this Radio to not show the image on front screen">
          <br>
          <br>
          <select name="submitter_47796" id="submitter_47796">
            <option value="none" selected="selected">(Select One)...</option>
            <option value="cDM" >cDM</option>
          </select>
          <br>
          Header Image&nbsp;&nbsp;
          <select name="headerImage_47796" id="headerImage_47796">
            <option value="0" selected="selected">No</option>
            <option value="1" >Yes</option>
          </select></td>
        <input type="hidden" name="mainID" value="5643" id="mainID">
        <input type="hidden" name="updmode" id="updmode" value="codes">
      <tr>
        <td colspan="4" align="left"><input type="button" name="Update" value="Update" class="mychecks" ></td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </form>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: unrelated - jQuery is way past 1.4.2

Answer (score 0):

After you submit the data via AJAX, you completely reload the DOM essentially so your `$('.mychecks')` and any other direct element references like that will be useless because you deleted them by saying `$('#reloadImages').load(...)`

To fix this, replace all of the `$('selector').event()` with **`$(document).on('event', 'selector', function() {...});`** and same with the non-event ones but use **`.find('selector')`** instead of `.on('event'...etc)` of course.

Example:

```
$(".mychecks").click(function(e) {
```

turns into

```
$(document).on('click', '.mychecks', function(e) {
```

and this

```
$("#frmImages").serialize();
```

can be this

```
$(document).find('#frmImages').serialize();
```

You should upgrade your jQuery to something more current (at least >1.7) to get functionality from what I give you here.  You can replace the event ones with `.delegate()` but at this point `.on()` has superseded it.

## HOWEVER

**I must advise against all of this** (even if it works) because this method is *very sloppy* and will probably lead to someone's browser crashing on an old PC, etc.  What you need to do is update **each element** individually and instead of basically grabbing a whole webpage using AJAX, only grab the actual **data needed** using JSON or other manageable format.

This will make your life much simpler and data manipulation and display will be a snap for you.

Comment: I would love to use the new formatted way, please guide me some sample code of doing it, it will be very useful for my future work. Regards

Comment: Do you mean what I mentioned at the end or the main answer?  I really, **really** prefer you follow the end note I included about proper data retrieval and updating with AJAX and the DOM.  But if you need more about the main answer the best resource I've found is actually the jQuery API itself.  Start here:  http://api.jquery.com/on/

Comment: Yes, following you i really mean to follow the last paragraph, i would love to use the approach that best suits

Comment: Although not a stellar tutorial, per se, this will help a lot with the coding (there's an annoying full-page ad FYI) http://www.w3bees.com/2013/08/ajax-image-upload-with-jquery.html

Comment: Thanks for the link, but the above answer you provided is not working, now when i click the update button, it does not nothing